# How long do demigods live for?

Tags: greek, demi-gods

I am wondering this, as it is a fascinating question in it's own right. I know that Heracles lived at about age 70-80, but what is the minimum, if not the maximum age a demigod can live.

Comment: It depends, clearly. I would imagine being a demigod is riskier than most jobs, so I would assume that the typical demigod life expectancy would be shorter than average. All the monster hunting and evil family members are not good for your health.

Comment: Even the gods are ordinary mortals without ambrosia.  I doubt that a demigod would live longer than other men -- though inconsistencies are rife in Greek mythology.

Comment: @267126 I meant their lifespan.

Comment: Tiny nitpick but Herakles became a god

Answer (score 8):

**Definitions**

Presumably by "demigods" you are referring to the relatively modern term as taken to denote a character from Greco-Roman mythology who is the offspring of a deity and of a human being.

The Ancient Greek *hēmítheos* and the Latin *semideus*, from which we get the English "demigod," do literally mean "half-god," but this is misleading. The ancient usage of these terms does not refer to a mortal who is literally half divine based on his/her parentage. Rather it is a term for a lower-tier divinity, a sort of minor god.

In Ancient Greek religion one can sketch out roughly three different levels of divinities who were honoured with cults: the *theoí* (gods); the *hēmítheoí*; and the *Hḗrōes* (Heroes). For the most part, the *theoí* were born immortal and had always been "the gods."

*Hēmítheoí* and Heroes were two different classes of divinities who typically tended to be dead humans who were recognised for their great deeds in life and therefore considered, in the afterlife, to have become powerful entities although lesser than the *theoí*. And it did so happen that a majority of them happened to have at least one divine parent.

Moreover the differences among these three different levels was not a permanent configuration, as demonstrated by the myth in which Herakles [Heracles] starts out as a Hero and then works his way up gradually to become a *hēmítheos* and eventually a full-blown *theós*, or, perhaps, more strictly speaking, he is considered to inhabit all three categories at the same time.

> In one story, after Herakles’ suicide, his remains could not be found
> on his funeral pyre, so his nephew Iolaos became the first to
> sacrifice to the dead hero as a *hemitheos* (demigod).
>
> According to Pausanias’ *Description of Greece*, Herakles had a son
> named Phaistos [Phaestus] who became king of the city of Sikyon. When
> Phaistos first arrived at Sikyon he found that the locals were making
> offerings to Herakles as a hero.
>
> > Phaistos then refused to do anything of the kind, but insisted on
> > sacrificing to him as to a *theos*. Even at the present day [`100s AD, over a thousand years after Herakles’ death`] the Sikyonians,
> > after
> > slaying a lamb and burning the thighs upon the altar, eat some of the
> > meat as part of a victim given to a *theos*, while the rest they offer
> > as to a hero.
> > [2.10.1]
>
> <sub>~ *from [my Answer to another
> Question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/2666/2682)*</sub>

**Lifespan**

As far as I am aware, the only extant ancient attestations of Herakles' age at death are in Clement of Alexandria's *Exhortation to the Greeks*, and Jerome's *Chronicon*, both of which are late sources by Christian authors. They both say that Herakles had lived for fifty-two years when his body burned on Mt Oita [Oeta]. (The ambiguous wording in Clement's text might possibly be implying that his source for this detail is either one of the Peripatetic philosophers Hieronymus or Dicaearchus.)

Jerome also adds that "certain people, however, write that he [*Herakles*] perished" when he was only thirty years old. Later yet than that, the *General History* of King Alfonso X of Castile (1200s AD) cites the common lifespan of fifty-two for the hero, but includes a note that certain accounts make Herakles forty when he died.

Even going by the more modern Riordanesque definition of "demigod," there is nothing particularly special about the lifespans of the children born from unions between humans and the Greco-Roman gods. For the most part, generally speaking, in terms of capabilities, durability and nature, they are just as mortal, vulnerable and human as all other ordinary men and women, pretty much indistinguishable from them.

Among these mortal progeny of the gods there are indeed some who stand out in a few different ways, but they are exceptions. Especially as far as lifespan is concerned, this is best illustrated by another son of Zeus, namely King Sarpedon of Lycia, who was slain in the Trojan War, despite Zeus's own desire to keep him alive. According to Apollodorus' *Bibliotheca* 3.1.2, Zeus had created a special dispensation for him to live for three generations, thus making him most likely the oldest person to fight in that war.

**Glitches in the Timeline**

Even ancient mythographers seemed to be a little bit incredulous at the idea that Sarpedon, who should have died something like a hundred years before the Trojan War, was one of the warriors defending Troy. This gave rise to two different versions of the character. In Homer's *Iliad* he does not seem to be a supernaturally old man, being the son of Zeus by Bellerophontes' daughter Laodameia. There is, however, also the version in which he is the son of Zeus and Europa, and thus one of the brothers of King Minos of Crete. In yet one other variant the Sarpedon who dies at Troy is the grandson of Minos' brother Sarpedon.

The mythology is somewhat replete with chronological discrepancies like this one. Minos himself is supposed to have died only one generation before the Trojan War. However, if he was the son of Europa, then by my calculations we would have to have been at least two hundred years old at death. Again, certain ancient writers, being aware of the issue, came up with similar explanations as those for his brother Sarpedon. The Minos who died a generation before the war at Troy, according to them, is the *grandson* of a more ancient Minos, who in turn was the son of Zeus and Europa.

On occasion, Herakles/Hercules also encounters individuals from long before his time in places like Egypt and India. The Roman writer Cicero explains this away by asserting that there were a number of different previous characters called Hercules, and some of them were children of Zeus (or rather of his Roman counterpart Jupiter) by yet *other* women.

It would be a clever hack to these anachronisms to deduce that these "demigods," because of their descent from the gods, are just that long-lived, and therefore could last a couple of centuries before growing old and perishing, but no ancient source makes such a claim. Hence all mortals, whether their parents are immortal or divine or not, are portrayed as suffering the same rate of decay as everybody else, unless extracurricular intervention is made on their behalf.

***Minimum* Life Expectancy**

Whatever age at which a regular garden-variety human can die is the same age at which a "demigod" can end his life, which is why Herakles' stepmother Hera tried to assassinate him when he was still a baby. Although that attempt failed, there are, in fact, quite gruesome stories featuring the deaths of infant children of certain deities.

In one, an Argive princess named Psamathe was raped by the god Apollon [Apollo] and bore him a son named Linos [Linus]. Being unmarried and still living in her father's house, Psamathe had managed to keep the birth a secret, but fearful of what her father might do, she abandoned the newborn outside where he was torn apart by the king's sheepdogs. (This tragedy is part of a story told to explain how a temple of Apollon came to be built on Mt Gerania.)

Comment: Excellent answer! Really covered all bases.

Comment: I appreciate that :-)

Comment: Added a detail from one more source

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any statements to the contrary, I think it is safe to assume that demigods have normal human lifespans for people of their rank and profession (i.e. Bronze Age soldiers and royalty). I can't recall any myths that mention, for example, a demigod dramatically outliving their non-demigod spouses, the way that Arwen is foretold to outlive Aragorn in LOTR.

Worth mentioning: similar to modern superheroes, ancient Greek Heroes were known to get into some shenanigans (e.g. entering and returning from the Underworld, ascending Olympus to become a true god, etc) that can make it tricky to even calculate their age at all. (Is Captain America 100 years old, or does being frozen for decades mean he's still just in his 30s? Did Herakles die in his 70s, or does becoming a god not count as dying?)

Ancient Greek myths also have fluid timelines, again similar to comic books, so you can't precisely date a Hero's lifespan based on external events, just like you can't pick a specific date for Batman's birth because his stories keep getting updated over time.

But overall, it seems that demigods age and die at about the same speed as normal mortals, unless they are killed in battle or murdered.

Comment: One notes that without ambrosia, the gods themselves aged, and there's no indication that they did so slowly.

Comment: @Mary That detail only appears in some versions of the mythos. For example, in The Iliad, the Olympians are specifically referred to as "the deathless gods" and "they who need neither food nor drink."

Answer (score 1):

In myths, demigods normally live for the average human lifespan, but there is no riskier job than the one demigods have. The only demigod that actually had a happy ending was Perceus, but most of the other ones died younger.